# using paste function on variable in data.frame doesn't work

Tags: r, soundcloud

I’m working on an error that is literally blowing my mind.
I isolated the user_id’s of some data from soundcloud and removed duplicates.
Now I’m trying to use the paste0 function, so I can get information on the separate users.

```
step3 <- paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", user_id, "?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'")
```

It comes back with the message

```
Error: object 'user_id' not found.
```

Now I was trying all sorts of different ways to go around the paste function, when I though I could try to make a ‘handmade’ dataframe as followed:

```
participant <- c(1:4)
user_id <- c(199647167, 199647179, 146469660, 128223886)
df <- data.frame(participant, user_id)
```

and now it neatly returned:

```
[1] "'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/199647167?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'"

[2] "'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/199647179?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'"

[3] "'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/146469660?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'"

[4] "'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/128223886?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'”
```

Exactly what I wanted! But on the ‘real’ dataframe it doesn’t work.
I’ve tried all sorts of things like copying the data to a new DF, renaming the column, clearing the working space, and much more.
I’ve attached an .Rda file with the user IDs. Can anyone make sense of it?

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=19951112717935170742

Comment: I take it that in your original attempt `user_id` is the name of a column in a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first call, `user_id` does not exist as a variable, so this returns an error:

```
step3 <- paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", user_id, "?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'")
Error: object 'user_id' not found.
```

Now the following:

```
participant <- c(1:4) #participant exits
user_id <- c(199647167, 199647179, 146469660, 128223886) #participant exits, user_id exists
df <- data.frame(participant, user_id) #participant exits, user_id exists, df exists
```

In line 2, you defined a vector `user_id`, which is now in the namespace. Assigning it to the data.frame does not remove it

Then you run your code again:

```
step3 <- paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", user_id, "?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'")
```

It pulls the `user_id` variable (the vector, not the data.frame column) from your environment. To also see why this works, try running `rm(user_id)` after the `df <-` line and then try running the `paste0` call. It should return an error because you cleared the vector.

To use the data.frame instead, you have to subset. The syntax would be:

```
paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", df$user_id, "?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'")
#or
paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", df[,"user_id"], "?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'")
#or
paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", df[["user_id"]], "?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d'")
```

Depending on what you want your return type to be